# Get Index of the first non printable character in Python

Tags: python

I would like to get the index of the first non printable character in a string so i could replace it by a new one.

For example: 
`indexNonPrintable("Hell[nonprintable] World!") = 4`

If possible, I would like to do it in an optimised way in python otherwise I could do it like this :

```
i = 0    
for c in str:
   if (c not in string.printable)
      return i
   i = i + 1
```

Comment: Use enumerate https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate

Answer (score 2):

Just for funsies, the one-liner:

```
def indexNonPrintable(s):
    return next(i for i, x in enumerate(s) if x not in string.printable)
```

That version raises `StopIteration` if no non-printable character exists; you could change it to:

```
    return next((i for i, x in enumerate(s) if x not in string.printable), None)
```

to return `None` on failure (or use `-1` to behave like `str.find`), or to:

```
    try:
        return next(i for i, x in enumerate(s) if x not in string.printable)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("No non-printable characters found")
```

to behave like `str.index` and raise `ValueError` when no matching character is found.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression for this. Something like this might work:

```
import re
import string

match = re.search('[^' + re.escape(string.printable) + ']', str)
if match:
    return match.start()
```

Comment: Given that \ and `]` are printable characters, you want to use `re.escape(string.printable)` to construct your regex, or this will misbehave subtly (really subtly, thanks to how `string.printable` is defined; it will consider \ to be non-printing, because it's interpreted as an escape, but it will still mostly work because the \ happens to escape the `]` that follows it, which would otherwise prematurely terminate the character class).

Comment: Good catch @ShadowRanger!

Answer (score 0):

you could convert each character to ascii using `ord(c)`.

```
i = 0    
for c in str:
   ascii_c = ord(c)
   if ascii in range(x,y)
      return i
   i = i + 1
```

where x and y are the integer values of the character from the [Table of ascii values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3etx3.png)

Comment: That doesn't really help matters much (especially if the `range` is inline, and therefore recreated on every test). You could improve it to just `if x <= ord(c) < y:` which avoids recreating a `range` object and avoids storing the result of `ord` to a named variable.